# Run whenComplete of CompletableFuture in original thread

Tags: java

How can I run `whenComplete` of the `CompletableFuture` in the original thread that CompletableFuture was created in?

```
    // main thread
    CompletableFuture
            .supplyAsync(() -> {
                // some logic here
                return null;
            }, testExecutorService);
            .whenComplete(new BiConsumer<Void, Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Void aVoid, Throwable throwable) {
                // run this in the "main" thread 
                }
            });
```

Comment: Just wondering: when you check the threads that get used here, both are in the test executor? I would have assumed that whenComplete() does what you look for already?

Comment: Simply put: You don't, because you would loose the benefits of async computation if you wait for the task to complete. More complex: In UI cases like Swing or JavaFX you can schedule a task to run after completion (SwingUtilities.invokeLater(), or Platform.runLater()).

Comment: @GhostCat No it doesn't. `whenComplete()` will be run on any of the async threads, but not on the original thread.

Comment: then what is the use of `@Async` here, you can do this task on main thread that creates async thread

Answer (score 1):

Expanded example for JavaFx:

```
    button.setOnClick((evt) -> {
        // the handler of the click event is called by the GUI-Thread
        button.setEnabled(false);
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            // some logic here (runs outside of GUI-Thread)
            return something;
        }, testExecutorService);
        .whenComplete((Object result, Throwable ex) -> {
            // this part also runs outside the GUI-Thread
            if (exception != null) {
                // something went wrong, handle the exception 
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    // ensure we update the GUI only on the GUI-Thread
                    label.setText(ex.getMessage());
                });
            } else {
                // job finished successfull, lets use the result
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    label.setText("Done");
                });
            }
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                button.setEnabled(true); // lets try again if needed
            });
        });
    });
```

This is not the best code you could write in this situation, but it should bring the point across.

Comment: thanks. What's hiding behind the `Platform.runLater`? I don't use java fx, so I'd prefer java se/ee example

Comment: The UI thread of JavaFX runs in an endless loop like this: He sleeps and waits for an event. If he gets one, then he decides what to do. If the event is for a UI component, then he passes that event to the component(s) and runs the event handlers of that component(s). The `runLater()` method triggers a special event, that contains a `java.lang.Runnable` that is then run on this UI thread. It passes a job to the UI thread, that should be run as soon as possible, but after the UI events are done. After that the UI thread issues the redraw on the screen and waits for the next event(s).